# How to specify the absolute path instead of the relative path

Tags: python, operating-system, sys

I am trying to read from a text file but such that I am able to pass the path to the file on the command line.

Like shown below,

```
path=sys.argv[1]

with open(path,"r") as filestream: 

for line in filestream:
    currentline=line.split(",")
    salt=currentline[0]
    X=int(currentline[1])
```

However, I am getting FilenotFound error when specifying the absolute path. It works when specifying the relative path.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you invoke this script with your absolute path?

Comment: The absolute path is most likely badly formatted, which we can't say for sure because you are not providing your command line calls

Comment: Paste the `traceback`, the `commandline` you ran, and the `file`'s `abspath` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing, you should `print(f'Openining {path}')` in order to see what the parameter actually is inside the program.

I suspect you are passing in a path that contains a space.  If you are using the path you specify on the command line has spaces in it then you will need to wrap the path in double quotes on Windows or escape the space with a backslash on, say, MacOS.

For example, on a Mac, I'm using `python3 test.py /Users/preston/Desktop/untitled\ folder/test.py` successfully.

Comment: Thanks alot! This solved the issue. The problem was with the space.

Comment: `python test.py "/Users/preston/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py"` will work in any POSIX shell, including the `bash` shell used by default on macOS. The quotes are just a shorthand for escaping every contained character with a backslash. `"foo"` is equivalent to `\f\o\o`.